# firebase console database display instantly flips back to Overview

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

In testing a firestore database and reviewing the results in the firebase console, the database data will not load and keeps returning to the Overview display. By using two devices to test with, I can determine that the updates are correct.
This problem started with one rogue record on the console causing the data display to backout but all other records were correctly displayed. Other project database records display correctly.
Is there any way I isolate the problem by finding an error message?

Comment: Are there any errors displaying in the dev console of your browser? Also: please make sure you disable any plugins that might be interfering, ad blockers being notorious for causing problems.

Comment: Yes. the error that is triggered when press the Database option indicates that there are non utf8 characters. I am not that familiar with the dev console. Using the android app I can start deleting the most recent entries, one at a time. It is just test data. I really like firestore and it is perfect for my project. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Please show the exact error message, as it's hard to determine what's going on without that.

Comment: The error message:

Comment: CSI/tbsd_
prompt_embed_static.js:370:606
CSI/_tbnd
prompt_embed_static.js:370:606
log:disconnect()
rs=AON9Pum9x33_rUdgc1MimbgnKKyl9KwO1g%20line%202329%20%3E%20eval:403:360

Comment: I am guessing the cause of the problem is the first two records that should appear on the console database were recorded as 12460\n\n\n and 12467\n. This was caused by accidentally pressing the next line on the textedit field. I can see this when I do a query on my device and display the document Id. I do not know how to delete them from the console

Comment: Aha.... I was able to reproduce it. This is a bug in the console indeed.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

This is indeed a bug in the Firestore console: if you select a document with a newline (`\n`) in its ID, the URL of your browser doesn't reflect the selected document.

Thanks for reporting! This will be fixed in an upcoming update to the Firebase console.

In the meantime, the API will allow you to access these documents without problems. So your apps should continue to work, and consider performing actions on affected documents through the API instead of through the console.